# Query with a subquery where results could be many

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a main table, tbl_vluchtgegevens which is the "main" table I'm looking at. From this, I want to JOIN tbl_photos and show a "random" result from this table.

My problem is that in the tbl_vluchtgegevens there is only 1 column value that would equal a column value in tbl_photos, however, there is a second column that is stored in tbl_photos which is similar to a second column in tbl_vluchtgevevens that it needs to look at. There is a 3rd table where the value in tbl_photos would have the value for tbl_vluchtgegevens, tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij

I just can't figure out the MySQL code for MariaDB. I'll try to display this below.

```
 tbl_vluchtgegevens     |     tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij     |    tbl_photos
 luchtvaartmaatschappij       luchtvaartmaatschappij
                              IATACode                             img_lvm
 inschrijvingnmr                                                   img_nmr
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
 tbl_vluchtgegevens
 gegevenID  |  luchtvaartmaatschappij  |  inschrijvingnmr  |  vertrekdatum2
 1             911                        N803NW              2018-01-01 12:00:00
 2             1702                       PH-AON              2018-01-15 17:00:00
 3             911                        N853NW              2018-01-17 11:00:00


 tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij
 luchtvaartmaatschappijID   |   IATACode
 911                            DL
 1702                           KL
 1803                           LH


 tbl_photos
 photoID   |   img_lvm   |   img_nmr   |   file
 1              DL            N853NW       somefile.jpg
 2              DL            N803NW       somefile2.jpg
 3              DL            N853NW       somefile3.jpg
 4              KL            PH-AON       somefile4.jpg
 5              KL            PH-AON       somefile5.jpg
 6              LH            D-AUBC       somefile6.jpg
 7              DL            N805NW       somefile7.jpg
```

Query would result:

```
 gegevenID  |  vertrekdatum2        |   luchtvaartmaatschappij  |  inschrijvingnmr  |  file
 1             2018-01-15 12:00:00       911                         N803NW             somefile.jpg
 2             2018-01-15 17:00:00       1702                        PH-AON             somefile4.jpg
 3             2018-01-17 11:00:00       911                         N853NW             somefile3.jpg
```

sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19e222/1

At one point, I've tried using the code below, but if multiple rows exist in tbl_photos, then it displays each row from tbl_vluchtgegevens with all of the rows in tbl_photos.

```
SELECT DISTINCT vg.gegevenID, vg.vertrekdatum2, vg.inschrijvingnmr, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID, p.*

FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg

LEFT JOIN tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij lvm
ON vg.luchtvaartmaatschappij = lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID

LEFT JOIN tbl_photos p 
ON lvm.IATACode = p.img_lvm
AND vg.inschrijvingnmr = p.img_nmr 

WHERE vg.vertrekdatum2 <=NOW() 
ORDER BY vg.vertrekdatum2 DESC
```

I've tried to do a subquery, too, but I've only done one and I can't get this to work no matter how I rework the code.

```
SELECT vg.gegevenID, vg.vertrekdatum2, vg.inschrijvingnmr, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID, p.*

FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens vg

LEFT JOIN tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij lvm
ON vg.luchtvaartmaatschappij = lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID

(   SELECT p.*, lvm.IATACode, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID
    FROM tbl_photos p 

    LEFT JOIN tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij lvm
    ON vg.luchtvaartmaatschappij = lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID

    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1 ) pho

WHERE vg.vertrekdatum2 <=NOW() AND vg.luchtvaartmaatschappij = pho.luchtvaartnamatschappij AND vg.inschrijvingnmr = pho.img_nmr
ORDER BY vg.vertrekdatum2 DESC
```

Comment: I think its better that you show some example data on http://www.sqlfiddle.com and create ascii data tables (formatted text) what results you expect.. Reverse engineering SQL with some text to a working SQL code is almost impossible to do... The Dutch lauguage within the SQL code makes it even harder for non Dutch speaking people

Comment: I've figured out the sqlfiddle and here is the link    http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19e222/1

Comment: updated file: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be9f7/1   i can get it to display a record, but I'd like to have a random row from tbl_photos ...

Comment: i've posted a answer that matches the output where you say "Query would result:" in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is with a co-related subquery

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   tbl_vluchtgegevens.gegevenID
 , tbl_vluchtgegevens.vertrekdatum2
 , tbl_vluchtgegevens.luchtvaartmaatschappij
 , tbl_vluchtgegevens.inschrijvingnmr
 , (
     SELECT 
       tbl_photos.file
     FROM 
       tbl_photos
     WHERE
       tbl_photos.img_nmr = tbl_vluchtgegevens.inschrijvingnmr
     ORDER BY 
      RAND()
     LIMIT 1
    ) AS `file`
FROM 
 tbl_vluchtgegevens

WHERE
 tbl_vluchtgegevens.vertrekdatum2 <=NOW() 
ORDER BY
 tbl_vluchtgegevens.vertrekdatum2 DESC
```

**One Possible Result**

```
| gegevenID |        vertrekdatum2 | luchtvaartmaatschappij | inschrijvingnmr |          file |
|-----------|----------------------|------------------------|-----------------|---------------|
|         2 | 2018-01-01T17:00:00Z |                   1702 |          PH-AON | somefile5.jpg |
|         1 | 2018-01-01T12:00:00Z |                    911 |          N803NW | somefile2.jpg |
|         4 | 2017-03-01T17:00:00Z |                    911 |          N809NW |        (null) |
|         3 | 2017-01-17T11:00:00Z |                    911 |          N853NW | somefile7.jpg |
|         4 | 2016-03-01T17:00:00Z |                   1702 |          PH-AON | somefile3.jpg |
```

see demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be9f7/29

Comment: Thanks. This does exactly what I wanted, to a point. The only thing it does not do is allow for multiple columns (which I realize I didn't specify and thus is not a fault of yours). For that, this type of query did not work.  but for the time being, this will work. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: "The only thing it does not do is allow for multiple columns (which I realize I didn't specify and thus is not a fault of yours). For that, this type of query did not work. but for the time being, this will work" @DaniëlCronk What do you mean? MIght be better if you asked a new question and maybe post a link in this comment section so i maybe can help you again..